# Could not parse LLM output in langchain when I request a specific JSON structure from an agent

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pydantic, agent, langchain

I'm trying to integrate the google search api to my constructed agent where the agent needs to create a specific json structure to a given paragraph. The given paragraph will be tasks that was done by an engineer. So the agent should be able to identify the tasks and issues that the engineer had come up in a particular day. My agent is displayed in the following code block

```
agent = initialize_agent(tools=[google_search_tool],
                                 agent=AgentType.CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
                                 llm=llm,
                                 memory=conversational_memory,
                                 max_iterations=5,
                                 early_stopping_method='generate',
                                 verbose=True,
                                 agent_kwargs={
                                     "system_message": CUSTOM_TIMESHEET_SYSTEM_PROMPT.strip(),
                                 },
                                 handle_parsing_errors=False
                                 )
```

Once I pass the message into the agent, the agent identifies all the tasks but throws an exception with the constructed JSON. The error is the following block.

````
ile "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\langchain\agents\conversational_chat\output_parser.py", line 50, in parse
    raise OutputParserException(f"Could not parse LLM output: {text}") from e
langchain.schema.output_parser.OutputParserException: Could not parse LLM output: ```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "task": "Completed the implementation of the user authentication feature",
            "duration": "8 hrs"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "task": "Wrote tests for the user authentication feature",
            "duration": null
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "task": "Plan to start working on the user profile feature",
            "duration": null
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "task": "Creating the database schema for the user profile feature",
            "duration": "4 hrs"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "task": "Start with the backend implementation for the user profile feature",
            "duration": "4 hrs"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "task": "Complete the backend implementation for the user profile feature",
            "duration": "8 hrs"
        }
    ],
    "problems": []
}
````

And this is the system message I passed into my agent.

````
CUSTOM_TIMESHEET_SYSTEM_PROMPT = """
Assistant is a large language model trained by OpenAI.Assistant is designed to be able to assist with you to breakdown tasks and the issues,
that were encountered through out the day. Assistant will break down the tasks and problems that were encountered by you.
Overall, Assistant is a powerful system that can help you to break down tasks and identify the problems that were encountered through given content.

TOOLS
------
Assistant can ask the user to use tools to look up information that may be helpful in answering the users original question. The tools the human can use are:

> Google Search: Search Google for most recent data, latest data, any question you don't know the answer such as current date, time, weather, president, etc
 

RESPONSE FORMAT INSTRUCTIONS
----------------------------
Please provide a structured list or breakdown of the individual work actions/tasks and problems faced mentioned within the paragraph.
Ensure each task is clearly separated and identified with the time spent on each task. Provide the identified tasks as a JSON array. 
Ensure that the tasks are clearly separated. Make sure to extract the time from hours. 
If the time is provided through a different metric, convert it to hours. One day means 8 hours, and half a day means 4 hours. 
One morning, afternoon, and evening will be equal to 4 hrs. Make sure to add hrs as the metric to the value. 
If the duration is not identified, make sure to keep duration null in the JSON. The identified problems should be identified as another JSON array. 
Id can be an incremental id. recommendedLinks should be solutions for the identified problems from YouTube.
When responding to me, please output a response in this format:

Option 1:
Use this if a problem is identified to recommend links from a tool.
Markdown code snippet formatted in the following schema:
```json
{{
    "action": any, # The action should be the google search
    "action_input": string # The identified problem
}}

Option #2:
Use this if you want to respond directly to the human. MARKDOWN code snippet formatted in the following schema:
```json
{{ 
    "action": any,
    "action_input": string # You should put what you want to return to use here
}}

Make sure to return the constructed JSON as a string
USER'S INPUT
--------------------
Here is the user's input (remember to respond with a markdown code snippet of a json blob with a single action, and NOTHING else):
````

I'm just expecting to return this mentioned as an output without any exception. Any idea how to solve this issue. Just keep noted that I passed `handle_parsing_errors=True` but this resulted in a loop which will end up in an error from the gpt side. Once I passed `handle_parsing_errors="Check your output and make sure it conforms! "` It will only out put a paragraph similar to `"Based on your last comment, you have successfully completed the implementation of the user authentication feature and wrote tests for it. You are planning to work on the user profile feature, starting with creating the database schema and then the backend implementation. You expect to complete the backend implementation by tomorrow afternoon and currently, you do not foresee any blockers. If any arise, you plan to communicate it in the team's communication channel and update the estimated timeline accordingly."

Comment: It's pretty naive to think that chatgpt is going to give you well formatted immediately parseable json in all cases, but if I read your error correctly it's wrapping the output in markup tags you're not attempting to remove.

Comment: @possum Yeah so the markups are added from the agent chain itself. Once I on the debugger I can realize that the json was created from the chain but was not outputted. This happens due to the integrated tool. `[tool/start] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 16:tool:invalid_tool] Entering Tool run with input:
"{'requested_tool_name': 'describe_tasks', 'available_tool_names': ['Google Search']}"
[tool/end] [1:chain:AgentExecutor > 16:tool:invalid_tool] [0ms] Exiting Tool run with output:
"describe_tasks is not a valid tool, try one of [Google Search]." ` Because of this chain will restart it's process.

Comment: @possum I'm pretty new to this field. What I can see the result in an exception but not as a proper output.

Answer (score 0):

LLMs don't always produce valid JSON, and you can't force them to regardless of the prompting technique. So you need to come up with some way to sanitize the JSON before parsing.

The [GoodAI-LTM library](https://github.com/GoodAI/goodai-ltm) has such a method: sanitize_and_parse_json().

Answer (score -1):

While it is true that you cannot expect LLMs to always produce parseable JSON, you can still use some turnarounds to accomplish your goal. Here are some of them:

1. Simplify the JSON format. Depending on what LLM you are using, it might not be fine tuned to handle JSON responses. You can ask something like, separate the strings with `~` and from the response, manually make a JSON object. If you can use GPT-4 Turbo, this will not be an issue.
2. Try a simpler format, you can ask the LLM to output an array, or any other linear data structure. You can then parse the output and fill you JSON object.
3. You can make multiple calls to the LLM, depending on the criticality of the information, you can group values and make multiple inference calls. This technique will also provide you with far better responses than before. Since now the model doesn't has to account for strict JSON formatting.

Finally, if you have the relevant resources, you can fine tune the LLM on your schema. It will almost always return the right format after that.